# How to send request to telegram API (chatJoinRequest)?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm sending GET request to telegram API

`https://api.telegram.org/botYYYYY/chatJoinRequest?chat_id=-1001959211654&user_id=254981096`

And getting 404 error
`{ "ok": false, "error_code": 404, "description": "Not Found" }`
Doc is [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatjoinrequest)
What is wrong? Bot id is correct, because I use it in other requests.

I want to create telegram chat join request

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), There is no method called `chatJoinRequest` (But there is a type available called [`ChatJoinRequest`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatjoinrequest)). So the request you are sending is invalid.

Please read the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatjoinrequest) for more info.